# How to connect Visual Stuido Code to virtualenv or my problem about virtualenv?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, scrapy, anaconda

I installed the Scrapy framework. In scrapy docs, its says I should create a virtual env of Anaconda for Scrapy so I did it. It works in anaconda virtual env but in vscode, it gives me a warning

"Import "scrapy" could not be resolved"

Everything works in cmd of virtual env, but the editor gives me a warning

What should I do?

Comment: In the left side of the bottom line is a feature to select the venv (if the Python extension is installed and a Python file open)

Comment: @lper Özyurt Have you selected the anaconda environment in the  VSCode?

Comment: Your question title is quite misleading. Using the actual error you're trying to resolve i.e., `vs code: import scrapy could not be resolved` is better and would enable other developers in need of the ensuing solution locate the Q&A thread faster

Answer (score 1):

First activate the virtual environment from cmd and then enter 'code .' to open the folder in VSCode. The python extension for some reason (at least in my case) does not recognize the virtualenv when using the python extension option in the bottom panel.

Also, if you are getting warnings from 'pylance' and are sure that you have the library installed, you can simply ignore the warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out any of these steps to resolve the issue.

1. Ensure you have activated the target virtual environment: You can use `conda activate <your_environment_name>` command to activate target virtual environment
2. Select the python interpreter in your target virtual environment: Open the Command Palette by pressing Cmd+Shift+P (MacOS) or Ctrl+Shift+P (Windows/Linux) and type `Python: Select Interpreter` in the Command Palette. Select your Anaconda virtual environment from the list. This will ensure that Visual Studio Code uses the correct Python interpreter associated with your virtual environment
3. If error is unresolved at this stage, restart vs-code
4. If error persist still, you might consider reinstalling scrapy